# Entity Framework - Saving child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF and WebAPI and trying to save a new object that has many child properties (eg city, country, etc). The data for these properties is pulled from an external source but I want to save them to my database along with my object for reporting purposes. For that reason I need to first check if the new child being passed along with the new parent already exists (remember, it's not being pulled from my database).

If I've selected, for example, a city I've already saved, it saves a duplicate row because the object passed in doesn't have MY city ID so EF thinks it's a new item.

I've tried attaching if it is already in the DB but it won't let me attach. It says the item is already being tracked by the context.

Here is my code for trying to check and save one of the child collections before saving the new parent.

```
foreach (HBCountry country in hbcampaign.HBTargetingSpec.HBCountries)
{
     if (db.HBCountries.Any(c => c.country_code == country.country_code))
     {
         country.CountryID = db.HBCountries.Where(c => c.country_code == country.country_code)
                                           .FirstOrDefault()
                                           .CountryID;
         db.HBCountries.Attach(country);
     }
     else
     {
         db.HBCountries.Add(country);
     }                 
}
```

I need to grab the ID of the existing entity from my context but after that I can't attach and let EF know that it doesn't need to create a new entry for this item.

I'm pretty new to EF and I'm constantly struggling with saving / updating any entities that have child collections. I can't seem to wrap my mind around when things are attached to the context and when not etc.

Comment: You're attaching already tracked entity. Just get the parent and either use parent.Childern.Add() or parent.ChildernId = id to add child entity. I hope you're not using Lazy Loading here.

Comment: It is better to use `Any()` than `Count() > 0`. `Count()` loop through the whole collection, `Any()` without a predicate just peeks at the first item and returns.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my code to use Any(). I'm still stuck though. If I was pulling the child properties from my own data source this wouldn't be as big a problem but because I'm basically sending in a "new" item each time (ie it doesn't have an ID from my DB yet). Sorry if this is very silly. I'm really struggling to get to grips with EF.

Comment: Does your country_code have a unique constraint on it in the database ?  If not I'd try adding one and using attach again.

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to set the Id, just create a new list with the existing country entities (and make as few queries as possible):

```
var newList = new List<HBCountry>();
foreach (HBCountry country in hbcampaign.HBTargetingSpec.HBCountries)
{
     var countryMatch = db.HBCountries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.country_code == country.country_code)
     if (countryMatch != null)
     {
         newList.Add(countryMatch);
     }
     else
     {
         newList.Add(country);
     }                 
}

hbcampaign.HBTargetingSpec.HBCountries = newList;
```

This is probably not the very best way to do this, but it's the first one I could think of.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried that earlier. It can't assign to country in this case as it is a foreach iteration variable.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much. As you say, probably not the best way to do it but it works and I'm running out of time. Thanks again =)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a unique constraint on the country_code column doesn't fix the problem attaching the entity.  I'd try this...

```
var countryCodes = hbcampaign.HBTargetingSpec.HBCountries.Select(c => country.country_code);
// Gives you the list of existing countries in one SQL query
var existingCountries = db.HBCountries.Where(c => 
    countryCodes.Contains(c.country_code);  

foreach (HBCountry country in existingCountries)
{
    var existingCountry = hbcampaign.HBTargetingSpec.HBCountries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.country_code == country.country_code);
    existingCountry.CountryID = country.CountryID;
    db.HBCountries.Detach(country);
    db.HBCountries.Attach(existingCountry);
}

var newCountries = hbcampaign.HBTargetingSpec.HBCountries.Where(c => !existingCountries.Any(c2 => c2.country_code == c.country_code);
foreach (HBCountry country in newCountries)
    db.HBCountries.Add(country);
```

Or even simpler, just assign the values on existingCountry from Country.  In my little universe I'd code generate a solution for this using T4 templates...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx